# しかも and なお both mean "furthermore; in addition; nevertheless" but here they are used together

Tags: usage

I was looking up しかも - "furthermore; nevertheless" from this sentence:

> しかも敵との間合いはキープしたままだ。
>   Nevertheless keep just within range of the enemy

but I am confused by this usage I saw on alc.co.jp

> しかもなお悪いことに
>   worse still

Rikaichan tells me that なお has a very similar meaning to しか yet here they are used together when I feel that just しかも would suffice.

Could somebody explain this please?

Comment: Extra emphasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This becomes clearer if you consider the whole sentence. Let's say we have two facts:

> ドーナツが一個しかない。そのドーナツが腐っている

We can change this to

> ドーナツが一個しかなく、しかもそのドーナツが腐っている

To indicate "in addition to that", or "on top of that".

Separate from this, let's say we wanted to eat lots of donuts. Given the facts we might say:

> ドーナツが一個しかないのは悪い。そのドーナツが腐っているので、もっと悪い

This can be made more natural by changing it to:

> ドーナツが一個しかなく、なお悪いことにそのドーナツが腐っている

So there are two different meanings here. One is that something happened on top of another thing, and that there is a bad situation, which became worse. Combining these, we can say:

> ドーナツが一個しかなく、しかもなお悪いことにそのドーナツが腐っている

Comment: I thought you might be a native speaker.  If you were, you would surely know that it would be pretty unnatural for us to say ドーナツが一個しかないのは悪い。そのドーナツが腐っているので、もっと悪い.  That is not how we use the word 悪い, particularly in the first sentence.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: I can guess you are a Japanese netizen ;) I am a native speaker. I just inserted the sentence to explain the logic behind. Hence the note "This can be made more natural by changing it to".